# I would like to find a sustainable Cellular router solution with management features

Tags: router, programmable

I would like to find a sustainable Cellular router solution with management features.

I would like to have a router that can be programmatically configured.  Some of the associated features would include:

- Monitoring data rates for each user and store such in selectable locations.
- Read and record data rates.
- Select specific towers and frequency bands.
- Change APN and switch SIM cards.
- The device could reside in a desktop slot or USB connection.
- Battery not required; if provided, not installing it should not disable operation.
- No wireless network required.
- GB Ethernet required.

If there are other considerations, I would like to hear more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an all-in-one managed device, you will need to go commercial and get something like the [Digi TX54](https://hub.digi.com/support/products/cellular-routers/digi-tx54/). That level of control doesn't exist in consumer gear. Netgear and others make all-in-one router modem combos, but the level of management is minimal.
Edit: I just stumbled upon [this combo](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BBVFP8HR) that gives you a commecial solution at a consumer price. You will need to get additional antennas for it.

I recommend the [Netgear LM1200](https://www.netgear.com/home/mobile-wifi/lte-modems/lm1200/), I have used one myself and it works great. It is a modem only, so it needs to be paired with a separate router. That would allow you to choose a router that allows more management of downstream devices. Since you mention a desktop slot, you could even do your routing in software for maximum control, logging, and programmability.

In either case, you will not be able to manage your upstream connection. Your tower connection, frequency band, and handoffs are handled by the network (3G, 5G, etc), not by the UE (user equipment).